# How to read two number variables in a single line using batch

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to read two numbers in the same line say 'a' and 'b' and want to read many lines from a text file. How can I make it ?

Comment: I don't understand how those two things are related. Can you please edit your question to include code you have tried, or an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file contains

```
1 2
3 4
17 26
```

then

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (yourtextfilename.txt) do (
 echo %%a
 echo %%b
)
```

should produce

```
1
2
3
4
17
26
```

since you don't tell us how you want to use these numbers it's impossible to advise further